# Spring data, find by property of a nested object

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have the following code:

```
@Entity
public class StudentEntity {
    @Id
    private String id;
    private Student student;
    ...
}


public class Student {
    private String name;
    private List<Grade> grades;
}


public class Grade {
    private String className;
    private String grade;
}
```

I've set up a spring data mongodb repository and I'm trying to create a method that will return me a `List<Student>` based on a `className` that I pass in as parameter. Based on everything I've read, I assumed that the following would work:

```
public List<Student> findByStudentGradesClassName(final String className);
```

but that gives an error saying that the parameter type should be a `Grade` object. I really only want to pass in a `String className`.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 99, accepted):

You would have to separate nested fields with underscore:

```
public List<Student> findByStudent_Grades_ClassName(final String className);
```

Note, that you still have to start field names with uppercase.

Comment: Using Spring boot 2.1.8 / spring data 2.1.10 I found the underscores are not necessary. Tested on a @ManyToOne (so not a list) nested field and using a countAll... statement in the repository.

Comment: Underscore still comes in handy, for example if you have X.myName and X.MY.name relations. I know it is uncommon scenario but I have a requirement to duplicate value both in X and in related component. Both will match FindByMyName thus error. Fortunetly FindByMy_Name wokrs as expected then.

Comment: Sonarqube does not like underscores in a method name.

Comment: @Akash the rule can always be disabled, it's more readable, because you clearly see the level in your hierarchy

Comment: @Andronicus Sounds like a Sonarqube problem.