# Mongo Repository find object by value in nested HashMap

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I have the following models:

```
public class Document {
  @Id
  private Stirng id;

  private HashMap<Language, LanguageDocument> languageDocuments;
}
```

```
public class LanguageDocument {
  private String title;
}
```

The Document class is a MongoDB collection that I can access via a MongoDB repository. I want to search for `Document`s by the titles (saved in the nested `HashMap languageDocuments`).
The following query method doesn't work for `HashMap` (return 0 objects) but it would work if `languageDocuments` would be a `List<LanguageDocument>` (analog to [Spring data, find by property of a nested object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55579240/spring-data-find-by-property-of-a-nested-object/55579268)).

```
public interface DocumentRepository extends ReactiveMongoRepository<Document, String> {
  Flux<Article> findByLanguageArticles_Title(String title);
}
```

How would I search for `Document` objects by an attribute in a nested `HashMap` object?